# MultiValueDictKeyError at /

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

with a post request locally (pycharm) everything works, but not on the server
I can’t figure out what the problem is, I see that I can’t find doc_id but I don’t understand why

post

```
{
    "customer_id":"1",
    "field":
    {
        "Number_doc_str":"32",
        "company_1":"РосРеестр",
        "company_2": "ИП Иванов",
        
    },
 "doc_id": 2
 }
```

view.py

```
class AddDocument(APIView):


def post(self, request):
    data = request.data  
    document = Document.objects.get(id=data['doc_id'])
```

Error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /adddocument/
'doc_id'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://constructor.site/adddocument/
Django Version: 3.2.11
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'doc_id'
Exception Location: /var/www/u1576304/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-      packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  /opt/python/python-3.7.0/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.10
Python Path:    
['/var/www/u1576304/data//www/constructor.site/Constructor',
'/var/www/u1576304/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
'/var/www/u1576304/data/www/constructor.site',
'/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts',
'/opt/python/python-3.7.0/lib/python37.zip',
'/opt/python/python-3.7.0/lib/python3.7',
'/opt/python/python-3.7.0/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/opt/python/python-3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 23 Jan 2022 14:25:02 +0000
```

Comment: Try to print the data and make sure that the doc_id is there, as this error as you have said it yourself is because doc_id is not there

Comment: so the point is that everything works on the local server, but not on the web server

Comment: did you run collectstatic?, check the request.data (check in the browser network too)and make sure 'doc_id' i sending

Comment: @Jisson запускал collectstatic
here's what it contains request.data:
<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': [' {\"customer_id\":\"1\", \"field\":{\"Number_doc_str\":\"32\", \"company_1\":\"РосРеестр\", \"company_2\": \"ИП Иванов\"}, \"doc_id\": 2}']}>/n"